# How to get rid of duplicate SQL results when aggregrating from 2 linking tables without using distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question is a performance question.

Given this postgresql, I get this result.

```sql
select fp.fp_id post_id, 
tag_linking_table.sehset_tid hashtag
FROM soc_ent social_entity
JOIN fp on fp.fp_id = social_entity.se_id
LEFT JOIN sehset tag_linking_table on tag_linking_table.sehset_seid = social_entity.se_id
GROUP BY post_id, hashtag
```

[image]

I can see that the `post` ending in `89` has 2 hashtags. All good so far.

I now modify the query to get the following expected result.

```sql
select fp.fp_id post_id, 
jsonb_agg(tag_linking_table.sehset_tid) hashtag
FROM soc_ent social_entity
JOIN fp on fp.fp_id = social_entity.se_id
LEFT JOIN sehset tag_linking_table on tag_linking_table.sehset_seid = social_entity.se_id
GROUP BY post_id
```

[image]

All good so far. My hashtags are properly grouped. Now if i changed the query to get the `likes` count using the same method above, this is my expected result

```sql
select fp.fp_id post_id, 
count(social_entity_likes.se_likes_ca) likes
FROM soc_ent social_entity
JOIN fp on fp.fp_id = social_entity.se_id
LEFT JOIN se_likes social_entity_likes on social_entity.se_id = social_entity_likes.se_likes_seid 
GROUP BY post_id
```

[image]

So in summary, my post ending in `89` has 2 likes from the `Likes` linking table, and 2 `Hashtags` from the hashtag linking table.

Now comes the problem. I want to display the hashtags and the likes in one sql query, so i modified the sql to the following.

```sql
select fp.fp_id post_id, 
jsonb_agg(tag_linking_table.sehset_tid) hashtag,
count(social_entity_likes.se_likes_ca) likes
FROM soc_ent social_entity
JOIN fp on fp.fp_id = social_entity.se_id
LEFT JOIN sehset tag_linking_table on tag_linking_table.sehset_seid = social_entity.se_id
LEFT JOIN se_likes social_entity_likes on social_entity.se_id = social_entity_likes.se_likes_seid 
GROUP BY post_id
```

But oddly, my result was this:

[image]

The solution I found was to add the word `distinct` inside the aggregation function which gave me the correct results.

```sql
select fp.fp_id post_id, 
jsonb_agg(distinct tag_linking_table.sehset_tid) hashtag,
count(distinct social_entity_likes.se_likes_ca) likes
FROM soc_ent social_entity
JOIN fp on fp.fp_id = social_entity.se_id
LEFT JOIN sehset tag_linking_table on tag_linking_table.sehset_seid = social_entity.se_id
LEFT JOIN se_likes social_entity_likes on social_entity.se_id = social_entity_likes.se_likes_seid 
GROUP BY post_id
```

[image]

But I am told every where that `distinct` will degrade the performance (and especially since i will have very large tables).

**Question**:  What caused my duplicate problem? and is distinct the correct way to fix it? And if so how can I get the same result without using the `distinct` keyword?  Thanks.

Comment: Note: for readability, please use table aliases for all referred tables.

Comment: Re `distinct` and performance - decent query optimizer most likely creates quite similar query plans for distinct vs aggregated queries, sometimes distinct can be faster and so on. BUT - using `distinct` often indicates that programmer has no clear undestanding about data or query structure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your duplicates were caused because you had two matches from `fp` to `sehset` and separately two matches from `fp` to `se_likes`. You haven't specified any restriction between `sehset` and `se_likes` so you get all the possible combinations (just like you would if you didn't specify a join condition for any join).

> But I am told every where that distinct will degrade the performance (and especially since i will have very large tables).

You probably need to stop listening to "everywhere" then.

Your only options are to apply some sort of "distinct" operation before the join or after it. There's logically no other alternative, is there?

You can see this sort of thing written with a group-by in a subquery sometimes:

```
SELECT fp.fp_id, like_counts.count
FROM fp
JOIN (
  SELECT something_matching_post_id AS post_id, count(*)
  FROM se_likes
  GROUP BY something_matching_post_id
) AS like_counts ON fp.fp_id = like_counts.fp_id
GROUP BY fp.fp_id
```

Whether that is any different from the other form in terms of performance depends on what other conditions you apply and how clever the planner is about each form.

Comment: `Your only options are to apply some sort of "distinct" operation before the join or after it. There's logically no other alternative, is there?` ok understood. I am not good a SQL, so i honestly didnt know alternatives or other solution besides distinct. If this is the only solution then i'll use it. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your join LEFT JOIN sehset tag_linking_table on tag_linking_table.sehset_seid = social_entity.se_id is pulling duplicated results. Its hard to see exactly what is going on, but I think you are joining the 'Politics' tag in the tag linking table to records that point to both the 'Politics' and the 'Technology' tags in the social_entity table. Ditto with the 'Technology' tag in the tag linking table.

Fix it with an AND in your join. LEFT JOIN sehset tag_linking_table on tag_linking_table.sehset_seid = social_entity.se_id AND linking_table.sehset.tid = whatever the corresponding filed is in the social_entity table. That might not be exactly right, but figure out why it is duplicating the join by running a select * query on just the join of those to tables with a where that limits the results to those records, and then correct it with an AND.

Comment: `your left join is pulling duplicated results` - this i do not understand how. Because this database only has the 5 Posts inside it (its just test data). Also, when i ran the queries individually, it gives the correct response. The problem only happens when i merge both queries together.